# wpf c# put in label in one window a value from another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label

I have a gui for a smart city in WPF C# 
I have 2 Window Forms.In the first i have a combobox.In the second I have a label.I have a button in the first that save my selected combobox value and proceed to the second window.

The code on button_click is :

```
ComboBoxItem typeItem_a = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox_a.SelectedItem;
string destination_a = typeItem_a.Content.ToString();       
Window1 SmartPlan2 = new Window1();
this.Hide();
SmartPlan2.ShowDialog(); // change window
```

Now i want to Set that string i saved (string destination_a) as label in the second window,automatically.Any ideas?

Comment: u have to use same datacontext and bind  the value

Comment: How about just send it to the constructor of Window1 and inside there put it in the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ragavan is right, you really want to try and do it with MVVM, here's an example of how what you want can be done :

### Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="double_windiwed_mvvm.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:double_windiwed_mvvm"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="10">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

</Grid>
```

### Window2.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="double_windiwed_mvvm.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:double_windiwed_mvvm"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Name}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

### ViewModel.cs

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    private Person _selectedItem;
    public Person SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if(_selectedItem != null && _selectedItem.Equals(value)) { return; }
            _selectedItem = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged emplementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

### Person.cs

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Your Entry Point

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
vm.Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Bob" });
vm.Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Marie" });
vm.Items.Add(new Person { Name = "John" });

Window1 w1 = new Window1();
w1.DataContext = vm;

Window2 w2 = new Window2();
w2.DataContext = vm;

w1.Show();
w2.Show();
```

You use your window's DataContext to specify which ViewModel to use, if you give the same ViewModel to both, they will keep each other updated automatically.
I strongly suggest giving a look at how MVVM & Binding works with WPF.